# Rails 4.2 - dependent: :restrict_with_error - access errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

> :restrict_with_error causes an error to be added to the owner if there is an associated object
>   [rails association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

I have added the following to my code:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end
```

My understanding is when I try to delete an **Owner** that has dependent **things** then an error should be raised. In my show action in the `owners_controller` I try to access the errors but can not find them:

```
def show
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  @owner.errors
end
```

**UPDATE - Delete Code**

```
def destroy
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  @owner.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Owner Deleted Successfully"
  respond_with(@owner)
end
```

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show any attempt to delete `@owner`

Comment: @meagar my apologies. I've added the delete code. Rails automatically redirects to my show action after trying to destroy

Comment: Have you looked for errors inside `destroy`, after invoking `@owner.destroy`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your code...

```
def destroy
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  @owner.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Owner Deleted Successfully"
  respond_with(@owner)
end

def show
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  @owner.errors
end
```

At the point you are trying to access errors, there will not be any.

Errors are temporary. They do not persist with the object, and they do not cross requests. They only exist on the model in the same request that generated the errors.

The only point in your code at which errors will be available is *inside `destroy`*, **after** you call `@owner.destroy`. They will never be available inside your `show` action.

```
def destroy
  @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  @owner.destroy
  # You must check for @owner.errors here
  flash[:notice] = "Owner Deleted Successfully"
  respond_with(@owner)
end
```

Comment: You are exactly right. Thank you so much for your help. Do you know if there is anyway to modify the default error message as supplied by Rails?

Comment: Yes, you can override any and all errors in `config/locals/*.yml`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models