# Where are the errors displayed? restrict_with_error validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to use the restrict_with_error validation in Rails 4.2.

In this application, an area has multiple apartments. I want to prevent area from being deleted if it has apartments associated with it.

Here is the area model:

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :apartments, :dependent => :restrict_with_error
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Here is the view where the user can delete an area:

```
<% @areas.each do |a| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= a.id %></td>
        <td><%= a.name %></td>
        <td><%= a.notes %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', a, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this area?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If I try to delete an area that has associated apartments, it is restricted. However, no error is displayed.

This might be a very simple question, but where is the error displayed if the deletion is restricted?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You can look into it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29090902/rails-4-2-dependent-restrict-with-error-access-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the area errors. You can do so in the area controller like this:

```
  def destroy
    unless @area.destroy
      flash[:notice] = @area.errors.full_messages[0]
    end 
    redirect_to areas_path
  end
```